# converting .PNG to .ICO in C/C#

Tags: c#, icons, png

I want to convert .PNG files to .ICO files. I want to do it locally with out any internet dependency (so I can't use online tools like converttoico.com etc).

I found a wonderful tool called png2ico, but it has a restriction that it can only convert images of size 1X1 to 256X256. Although for now, I am modifying the PNG resolution (in C#) and compressing it to 256X256, and then using this tool to convert it to icon, but the image quality is not good at all.

Does any one know of any native library for doing this or any tool (free or paid) that can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: In C/C#? Not even C/C++ are the same languages, but in this case I think you should really make up your mind.

Comment: I Know :), What I meant was, I can use Interops if I get some Native API in C/C++ (even COM), or I could directly use any API provided with .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick library that can convert png to ico , you can find imageMagick for .NET here : http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ .

If you need a program to do that you can try with IrFanView in batch mode ...

Answer (score 45):

Probably a little bit late, but here´s some c# solution to this:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\test.ico"))
{
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\test.png");
    Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon()).Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful. Here is a Powershell version: http://sdrv.ms/13JmBDT

Just use: ConvertTo-Ico.ps1 [-Image] <string> [[-Destination] <string>]

Comment: The quality of the generated favicon is really bad.

Comment: @kipusoep - This code does not take into account the PNG Alpha channel.  It also assumes the PNG is square and of a size that is legal for an ICON.  But given a good size, and totally opaque PNG, this is the minimum necessary to convert.

Comment: Poor quality icons are generated this way, so https://gist.github.com/darkfall/1656050 is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 6):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the most awesome CLI image manipulation utility ever made:

```
convert image.png image.ico
```

It's that easy, and it works with virtually every format you throw at it.

Also, it has APIs for a quite a few different languages (C#, if I remember correctly).