# Convert png to high quality ico

Tags: c#, icons, png

Maybe this is a very easy problem to solve but I haven't found the perfect solution yet.
I'm trying to convert a png to ico with C# and found the question [converting .PNG to .ICO in C/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381455/converting-png-to-ico-in-c-c) which sort of gives a working solution as below:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\temp\test.ico"))
{
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\test.png");
    Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon()).Save(stream);
}
```

For my own project I have changed this approach slightly to:

```
string pngFile = "path/to/pngfile";
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pngFile))
{
   using (Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon()))
   {
      using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         icon.Save(stream);
         // something interesting with icon here
      }
   }
}
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that the resulting ico is of poor quality, I'm guessing it got resized to 16x16 and lost some of it's color depth, perhaps now only has 16 colors? How can I convert to a higher quality ico file?

Comment: You might try:  https://gist.github.com/darkfall/1656050.  I can tell you you're going to need something more robust than `GetHicon` because that's a quick and dirty method, and by no means meant to be lossless.

Comment: @DonBoitnott please post your comment as an answer. I manged to get it working with your suggestion and I believe this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you will need a more robust method than `GetHIcon()`.  It is more of a "quick and dirty" option, and by no means loss-less.

Here's an example of a class that can preserve image quality on the way to converting as ICO:

> https://gist.github.com/darkfall/1656050

Comment: Gr8 script works like a charm, but I'm hitting `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow` error if I try to generate an icon with height greater than 255 .. probably due to CBYTE() maximum allowed is 255 - do you have any workaround/suggestions for making high quality Icons using your code?

Answer (score 3):

Check http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627823/Fast-and-high-quality-Bitmap-to-icon-converter
This is a clear and fast solution to convert a bitmap to png

Answer (score 2):

In the referenced question the accepted solution uses imagemagick, which is a great image manipulation tool that gives you have the ability to control size, colour depth etc. when converting from png to ico. I would really suggest trying that solution.

Using the imagemagick utility would look something like

convert -resize x16 -gravity center -crop 16x16+0+0 input.png \
-flatten -colors 256 output/favicon.ico

(you could then control -resize and -colors to achieve what you are looking for.)

The same options should be available programmatically in C# through http://imagemagick.codeplex.com

Comment: Sorry for not having mentioned this in the question but I'd prefer not to be dependent on external libraries if possible. I'd consider your suggestion if everything else fails.