# How can I convert System.Drawing.Image to System.Drawing.Icon in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, image, icons, system.drawing

I've this code

```
var image = Image.FromFile(sPngFile, true);
```

and my goal is to open an handler of a png file, and as I wrote I obtain an Image, and I would like to convert it into one Icon in real time

I know in this way I can create the ico file from the png; interesting, but I guess it's not what I need

```
var image = Image.FromFile(sPngFile, true);
ImageButtonGraphic.Save(sIcoFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
```

suggestions? thank you in advance

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381455/converting-png-to-ico-in-c-c

Comment: IIRC `ImageButtonGraphic.Save(sIcoFile, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);` this won't work have you tried? I think GDI doesn't support Save with format Icon

Comment: Check this out http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q316563

Comment: Try this `image.Save("123.ico", ImageFormat.Icon);
            Icon ico = new Icon("123.ico");` this will result in exception. actually it stores picture as `PNG` format so it is not an `icon` and results in exception

Comment: May help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7122/Dynamically-Generating-Icons-safely

Answer (score 6):

you can try this but, I don't think It will return nice icons.

```
var bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(fname);
var thumb = (Bitmap)bmp.GetThumbnailImage(64, 64, null, IntPtr.Zero);
thumb.MakeTransparent();
var icon = Icon.FromHandle(thumb.GetHicon());
```